# Naive Bayes when word does _not_ exist in data set

Tags: naivebayes

if I have documents along the lines of

```
{'cat', 'hello cat'}
{'dog', 'hello dog'}
```

and a sentence,

```
{'hello cat'}
```

The Naive formula is

```
P(cat|hello,cat)
```

or

```
P(cat|hello,cat)=(P(hello|cat) * P(cat|cat) * P(cat)) / (P(hello)*P(cat))
```

But what do I do in the case where the word does *not* exist.

for a sentence,

```
{'hello duck'}
```

I cannot use

```
P(cat|hello,cat) = (P(hello|cat) * P(duck|cat) * P(cat)) / (P(hello)*P(duck))
```

as that will give me a division by zero, (or even 0 if I catch it before hand).

How do you calculate the case of a word with effectively no probabilities.

Shall I chose an arbitrarily small value?